# FRTB SBA Delta calculation for GIIR

Tags: market-risk, frtb

In FRTB Sensitivity based approach delta calcualtion forg GIIR we have the defined vertices 3M, 6M 1Y, 2Y,5Y,10Y,15Y,20Y,30Y.
Say for USD bucket we have risk factors as USD-OIS and USD-3M curve, when calculating the delta at 6M for USD-3M do we shift the current USD-3M curve at 6M tenor by 1 bp, I am cofnused as i keep seeing PVO1 and DVO1 which are paralllel shifts to the curve and may mean that shift the forward USD-3M curve at the 6M tenor by parrallel shift of 1bp, which of these is correct?
Also it mentions that the curvature risk is simpler and there is a parallel shift, what does it mean by this.
Thanks.